# SQL Server : convert datetime to string without loosing a key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing a `SELECT` and `JOIN` of multiple tables in SQL Server. I need to find a way how to convert `datetime` to string without loosing a key.

- `DB_CREATED_TIME` has a datatype of `DATETIME`
- `DB_UPDATED_TIME` has a datatype of `DATETIME`

My code:

```
SELECT 
    A.[CASE_ID], A.[ACTIVITY_ID], D.[TEXT_CONTENT], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.[WHEN_CREATED], 22), 
    A.[WHEN_CREATED],.....
```

I found a solution using this code:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.[WHEN_CREATED], 22),
```

But this makes my key empty string instead of field name.

```
   '': '05/22/19  4:01:35 PM',  <--- This is converted part
   WHEN_CREATED: 2019-05-22T16:01:35.180Z,<-- This needed to be a string.
   WHEN_MODIFIED: 2019-05-22T16:02:05.000Z,<-- This needed to be a string
   SUBJECT: 'Re: testr [#1216]',
```

How can I make my response for `DATETIME` be like this:

```
WHEN_CREATED: '05/22/19  4:01:35 PM',
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the issue? To me it's not clear what exactly you want to achieve and what's the problem.

Comment: I need my select query convert dateTime to string and return it. 

When i do this with "convert(varchar, A.[WHEN_CREATED], 22)"

Return which i am getting is :
"'': '05/22/19  4:01:35 PM',
Instead of:
 WHEN_CREATED: '': '05/22/19  4:01:35 PM'

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](http://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(20); ......` or whatever suits your needs - but **DO SPECIFY** a length for the `VARCHAR` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I fully understand the issue, but maybe... It looks to me that you should add a name for the output of the conversion.

```
select convert(varchar, A.[WHEN_CREATED], 22) as WHEN_CREATED
```

Comment: That works, but please remove  [] from second WHEN_CREATED because it will be an array. 
But your answer is correct. Thank you.